# How to solve error Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'validate' was called on null when logging in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-getx

I am trying to log in an already signed method user from my laravel database and i have this method i call when users tap on login - `controller.login()`

PS - i have two screens, different classes, different Global key :

- Screen the user inputs phone number :

```
Form(
              key: controller.loginFormKey,
              child: ListView(
                primary: true,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Image.asset(
                              "assets/icon/login_key.png",
                              width: 280,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Welcome Back',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Color(0xff34495E),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 5.0, left: 22.0, right: 22.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Fill in these details to log In as a \nmerchant',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        color:
                                            Color(0xff596780).withOpacity(0.8),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Obx(() {
                    if (controller.loading.isTrue)
                      return CircularLoadingWidget(height: 300);
                    else {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          FadeInDown(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Color(0xffeeeeee),
                                      blurRadius: 10,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 2),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                                      ignoreBlank: false,
                                      validator: (input) => !input
                                              .contains('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0')
                                          ? "Should be a valid phone number".tr
                                          : null,
                                      onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber value) {
                                        controller.currentUser.value
                                            .phoneNumber = value.toString();
                                      },
                                      initialValue: PhoneNumber(
                                          isoCode: 'NG', dialCode: '+234'),
                                      onSaved: (input) => controller.currentUser
                                          .value.phoneNumber = input as String,
                                      formatInput: false,
                                      selectorConfig: SelectorConfig(
                                        selectorType:
                                            PhoneInputSelectorType.DROPDOWN,
                                        useEmoji: true,
                                      ),
                                      cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                      inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                            bottom: 15, left: 0),
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                        hintText: 'Mobile Number',
                                        hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                          fontSize: 12,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          color: Color(0xff212121),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                            child: FadeInDown(
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  controller.login();
                                  Get.toNamed(Routes.PIN_INPUT);
                                },
                                color: Color(0xff34495E),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.18),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                                minWidth: double.infinity,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

],
                      );
                    }
                  }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

- Screen where the user inputs the pin :

```
Form(
      key: controller.loginPinFormKey,
      child: Container(
        width: 55,
        height: 55,
        child: Obx(() {
          return TextFormField(
            controller: widget.loginPinController,
            initialValue: controller.currentUser?.value?.password,
            onSaved: (input) => controller.currentUser.value.password = input,
            
            validator: (input) => input.length < 3
                                ? "Should be more than 3 characters".tr
                                : null,
            enabled: false,
            obscureText: true,
            obscuringCharacter: '*',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10),
                ),
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xff3498DB)),
              ),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              border: widget.outlineInputBorder,
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Color(0xffF8F8F8),
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );

 MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                           controller.login();
                        },
                        color: controller.isTextEmpty == true
                            ? Color(0xffD7D7D7)
                            : Color(0xff34495E),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.18),
                        ),
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                        minWidth: double.infinity,
                        child: Text(
                          'Next',
                          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ),
```

**`controller.login()` is called on the second screen,**

This is my controller and the method called :

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  final Rx<User> currentUser = Get.find<AuthService>().user;
  GlobalKey<FormState> loginFormKey;
  GlobalKey<FormState> loginPinFormKey;

void login() async {
    Get.focusScope.unfocus();
    if (loginFormKey.currentState.validate() &&
        loginPinFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
      await loginFormKey.currentState.save();
      loginPinFormKey.currentState.save();
      loading.value = true;
      try {
        await Get.find<FireBaseMessagingService>().setDeviceToken();
        currentUser.value = await _userRepository.login(currentUser.value);
        await _userRepository.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            currentUser.value.email, currentUser.value.apiToken);
        loading.value = false;
        await Get.toNamed(Routes.ROOT, arguments: 0);
      } catch (e) {
        Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
      } finally {
        loading.value = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get error when i hit the `onPressed` button that triggers my method :

First i thought it was because i use Getx and i wasn't properly using `Obx(){}` properly, but it turns out i have rechecked my code over and over and don't seem to know how.

How do i navigate through this problem that has kept me in this spot for so long ? :(

This is the screenshot of the error message :

[image: Error]

UPDATE

I have changed my `onPressed` in First Screen and this is what i added :

```html
MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  await loginFormKey.currentState.validate();
                                  await loginFormKey.currentState.save();
                                  Get.toNamed(Routes.PIN_INPUT);
                                },
                                color: Color(0xff34495E),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.18),
                                ),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                                minWidth: double.infinity,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Next',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                              ),
```

Then my Controller and my `login()` looks like this now  :

```html
void login() async {
    Get.focusScope.unfocus();
    if (loginPinFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
      loginPinFormKey.currentState.save();
      loading.value = true;
      try {
        await Get.find<FireBaseMessagingService>().setDeviceToken();
        currentUser.value = await _userRepository.login(currentUser.value);
        await _userRepository.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            currentUser.value.email, currentUser.value.apiToken);
        loading.value = false;
        await Get.toNamed(Routes.ROOT, arguments: 0);
      } catch (e) {
        Get.showSnackbar(Ui.ErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString()));
      } finally {
        loading.value = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

This time i get a different error message :

Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'currentState' was called on null.

:(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `loginFormKey` & `loginPinFormKey`.

```
class AuthController extends GetxController {
  final Rx<User> currentUser = Get.find<AuthService>().user;
  GlobalKey<FormState> loginFormKey = GlobalKey(); // Initialize this
  GlobalKey<FormState> loginPinFormKey = GlobalKey(); // Initialize this
```

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your reply, but it's now showing me a new error : 'Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey'. What could be the cause?

Also throwing some renderflex issues i didn't have before

Comment: Define global key in the UI side

Comment: @HarshSureja How do i do that? This is what i have as keys in each of the form... 1, `key: controller.loginFormKey`   2. `key: controller.loginPinFormKey,
`. Or is there any other way i have to define the keys?

Comment: @HarshSureja Hello sir?

Comment: if you want to use in one screen for that time it is better to define in UI side.

Comment: @HarshSureja I already have my keys defined in my UI, check my question sir